# What is the base of the logarithm for the purposes of Algorithms?

Tags: big-o

While considering O(log(N)) for time complexity, what is the base of log?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569702/is-big-ologn-log-base-e

Answer (score 15):

All logarithms are related by some constant. (Hence the [change-of-base formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base)). Because we generally disregard constants in complexity analysis, the base doesn't matter.

Usually, the base is considered to be 2, when deriving the algorithm. Consider a sort like [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). You can construct a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Properties_of_binary_trees) out of it, and the tree has a height of `log₂ n`, because each node has two branches.

Comment: I would bold face the second sentence in the first paragraph ("the base doesn't matter") to make it an even better answer.

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't matter, the relative complexity is the same regardless of the base used.

Comment: Hmmm. If you logically extend this statement, you would be saying that O(n^2) is the same relative complexity as O(n^3).

Comment: Not at all. Big diff between 1 million squared or cubed. But log2, log10, log100? Not much difference at all.

Comment: @Andrew Shepherd - That is not correct. log_a(2n) / log_a(n) = log_b(2n) / log_b(n) for any a and b

Comment: @Andres Shepherd: To expand on the other responses to your comment, log_a(n)/log_b(n) is a constant which is the same for all values of n.  The ratio of (n^2)/(n^3), on the other hand, grows as n grows.  Algorithmic complexity analysis is concerned with how resource requirements increase as n increases, so constants don't matter.  Values that vary with n do.

Answer (score 2):

One way to think of it is that O(log<sub>2</sub>X) = O(log<sub>10</sub>X) = O(log<sub>N</sub>X)