# How is the the number of digits "d" among "n" keys is of order log n?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I was reading wikipedia article on Radix sort and while describing its efficiency, it says

> Radix sort efficiency is `O(d·n)` for n keys which have `d` or fewer
>   digits. Sometimes `d` is presented as a constant, which would make
>   radix sort better (for sufficiently large `n`) than the best
>   comparison-based sorting algorithms, which are all `O(n·log(n))`
>   number of comparisons needed. However, in general `d` cannot be
>   considered a constant. In particular, under the common (but sometimes
>   implicit) *assumption that all keys are distinct, then `d` must be at
>   least of the order of `log(n)`*, which gives at best (with densely
>   packed keys) a time complexity `O(n·log(n))`.

Now what I don't understand is he line - **assumption that all keys are distinct, then `d` must be at least of the order of `log(n)`**
What exactly is it trying to say?

Comment: Numbering `n` keys requires `Log(n)` digits, so the keys are at least that long.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider key are distinct then we have `n` distinct key, now assume the biggest key is `k` , we know that because all the numbers are distinct so `k` greater or equals to `n`. so `k` have `log(k)` digits and it is at least `log(n)` so `d` is `O(log(n))`

**EDIT:**
To be more clear about `log` in base `10` and `2` and Big-O read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569702/is-big-ologn-log-base-e).

Comment: @Srivatskrishnan there is no difference between log in base 10 or 2 or 16 and ... there are all the same order. constant dont effects order.

Answer (score 0):

If all key are distinct then you can order them, and the biggest is at least n (considering positive integers only)

Then the number of digits of n is log10(n) that's why d is at least log(n)