# T(n) = 9T(n/3) + n^2 I don't know where I'm wrong

Tags: math, big-o

T(n)=9T(n/3)+n^2        T(1)=1       use master theorem   answer big-o nation

```
T(n)=9T(n/3)+n^2
=9(9T(n/3^2)+(n/3)^2)+n^2
=9^2T(n/3^2)+9(n/3)^2+n^2
=9^3T(n/3^3)+9^2(n/3^2)^2+9(n/3)^2+n^2
...
=9^kT(n/3^k)+9^(k-1)T(n/3^(k-1))^2+...+9^2(n/3^2)^2+9(n/3)^2+n^2

/*if (n/3^k)=1
n=3^k  
k=log_3(n)*/

=9^kT(1)+n^2(9/3^2)^k-1...+n^2(9/3^2)^2+n^2(9/3^2)+n^2          
=9^kT(1)+n^2*Sigma(0 to k-1)(9/3^2)                               
=9^kT(1)+n^2*k                                                    
=9^log_3(n)T(1)+n^2(log_3(n))
=n^log_3(9)T(1)+n^2(log_3(n))
=n^2+n^2(log_3(n))
=O(n^2(log_3(n))
```

O(n^2(log_3(n)) is my answer but in chatgpt3.5 the answer is O(n^2(log(n))
so why log_3 is gone? am i wrong?

Comment: The base of the logarithm is a constant factor, so it can be discarded for `O()`. If that is your question (I'm not entirely sure I understood it).

Comment: Also, ChatGPT does not give you "answers". It only gives "credible-sounding responses" and to do so it will lie and make up things that you can't tell are nonsense, but are complete nonsense. It'll seem right some times, and it'll even be right some times, but it doesn't know when it's right, and it doesn't try to be right. Don't use ChatGPT (especially not older versions like 3.5) as part of a verification process.

Comment: Also see [Is Big O(logn) log base e?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569702/is-big-ologn-log-base-e)